# How to store data of a web application in client side which will accessible from any device?

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, web

I am creating an online shopping cart web application using the React.js and Spring boot technologies and in my application I need to implement a watchlist to the user which user can save their favourite products for future buying. So I thought that using the server side db is a wastage of resources, because it's not a very important detail to my web application,and I have already planned to store the shopping cart details in my db. So the problem here is I need to know how to store these details in the client side and then how to access all those data from any browser(Including different devices) ? Ex:Ebay watch list

**I already red about the articles of local storage Api in React.js but in there also the limitation of only to a specific browser was there.**

Comment: You can't. There has to be a sync mechanism.

Comment: @Zekros Admines do you have any idea of then how those big sites like Ebay implemented this ?

Comment: How can you tell that these sites only store data to clients? Client only data is different than offline data sync support.

Comment: @Zekros Admines so do you suggest to use db as same as for shopping cart? Do you think these data are valuable ?

Answer (score 0):

Your objective is straight forward, but once you start implement it, you yourself will start asking many questions

for example, 
what if the user logs in via a different browser
what if the user has two accounts
etc..,

so technically one use case you can achieve without satisfying other cases

But, don't worry there is bright side
you can use firebase and store there